# How can I access the session of a rails app from a PORO?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I'm working on a wizard - a PORO module - for user's information. The goal is to forward the users to said wizard for him to complete his user profile if he attempts to make a booking (or similar action) with an incomplete profile.

After the last step of the wizard I would like to redirect the user back to the action he intended initially. For that I'm saving a session variable named ":user_return_to_from_wizard".

I can't seem to access the session variable from the PORO module. What can I do?

I tried of course

```
session[:user_return_to_from_wizard]
```

but that doesn't work. I guess something like

```
App::Application.session....
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass the session value from the controller (where `session` is readily available) into the module / wizard?

Comment: to further explain Stefan's comment ... `session`, being hash-like, is mutable, so if you pass it to the PORO method as an argument, and manipulate it there, the changes will remain when you access `session` afterward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably can't and should'nt - one of nice things of using PORO is to be able to use them outside of a specific context (HTTP and session in your case). What I would do is collect the information you need from the session and use it to initialize your wizard:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    return_url = session[:user_return_to_from_wizard]
    wizard = Wizard.new(return_url: return_url)
    ...
  end
end
```

This way you can still test/use Wizard independently and don't have to rely on session inside.